# How to make horizontal space between a dot and a text equal to horizontal space between the dot of numerical label of numbered list and its item?

Tags: spacing, lists

Yesterday I could swear the horizontal spacing between the end of the item-label (a number followed by dot) of a numbered-list and the item-text following that label is 5.2pt, although the output (\showoutput log) shows 5.0. After running some tests today, it's (surprisingly) not 5.2pt but 5.05. Considering today's code was not a copy of yesterday's (which cannot be recovered by now, unfortunately), most likely explanation is changes in the code. However, 5.05pt is still not 5.0. That's one issue I would like a feedback from you about.

The second issue is that there's no length macro I know of that defines the spacing in question (between a list-label and its item) while such macros are usually available for adjustment (so I can't adjust the spacing of the list).

Now let's go through the following demonstration.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item{}hello
  \end{enumerate}
  1.\ hello

  \newlength\spaceWidth
  \settowidth{\spaceWidth}{\ }
  \the\spaceWidth % 2.41211pt
\end{document}

...........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 1.
.........\glue 5.0
........\penalty 0
........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 hello

........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 1.
........\glue 2.41211 plus 1.20605 minus 0.80403
........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 hello
```

[image]

(Space of 2.41211pt is less than glue of 5.0pt.)

[image]

Replace `1.\ hello` with `1.\makebox[5.0pt]{}hello` (and remove `\the\spaceWidth`):

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item{}hello
\end{enumerate}
1.\makebox[5.0pt]{}hello

...........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 1.
.........\glue 5.0
........\penalty 0
........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 hello

........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 1.
........\hbox(0.0+0.0)x5.0, glue set 2.5fil
.........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.........\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
........\TU/Georgia(0)/m/n/10 hello
```

[image]

[image]

Perfect (so far)!

Now remove `\setmainfont{Georgia}`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Obviously, 5.0pt is NOT enough.

Let's try 5.05pt: replace `1.\makebox[5.0pt]{}hello` with `1.\makebox[5.05pt]{}hello`:

[image]

Perfect.

What's your take on it? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but the length you allude to has a name: it is `\labelsep`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your document, both strings start at different horizontal positions. This difference does not account to a whole number of pixels on your screen, so you can't perfectly align the dots. So comparing the position on the `h` becomes meaningless. If you look closely at your last picture containing both `hello`s, you see that the red line does not touch both dots in the same way.

To get a more meaningful picture, you can ask TeX to indent your text in the same way it indents the label:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item{}hello
  \end{enumerate}
  \settowidth\leftskip{1.} % Don't do this in a real document!
  \advance\leftskip -20pt
  \leftskip-\leftskip
  \noindent1.\makebox[5.0pt]{}hello
\end{document}
```

This moves the `1.   hello` to the right to align with the label list entry. Now both are perfectly aligned, both the `1.` and the `hello`. So the distance actually is exactly 5pt.